# Implementation of unique_ptr and make_unique for aligned memory

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I am working on a version of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` for aligned memory. The purpose of this is vectorization, e.g., SSE or AVX, which has higher alignment requirements than the underlying types.

My header providing `aligned::unique_ptr` and `aligned::make_unique` (compiles with C++11, no need for C++14 support):

```
#ifndef ALIGNED_H
#define ALIGNED_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

// The "make_unique" parts are copied from GCC (/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits), and
// were adapted for alignment.

namespace aligned {

/// For internal use only!
namespace details {

/// Deleter for single object in aligned memory, used by aligned::unique_ptr
template <class T> struct Deleter {
  void operator()(T *data) const {
    // Single object, was created by placement-new => destruct explicitly
    data->~T();
    // Data allocated by "posix_memalign", so we must "free" it.
    free(data);
  }
};

/// Specialization of Deleter for array of objects, used by aligned::unique_ptr
template <class T> struct Deleter<T[]> {
  void operator()(T *data) const {
    // Data allocated by "posix_memalign", so we must "free" it.
    free(data);
  }
};

/// Allocation function for aligned memory, used by aligned::make_unique
template <typename T, std::size_t alignment>
inline typename std::remove_extent<T>::type *alloc(std::size_t num) {
  // Ensure minimum alignment for given type
  std::size_t align = std::max(std::alignment_of<T>::value, alignment);
  // If T is an array type, we remove the "[]"
  using TYPE = typename std::remove_extent<T>::type;
  TYPE *mem = 0;
  int error = posix_memalign((void **)&mem, align, sizeof(TYPE) * num);
  if (error == EINVAL)
    throw std::logic_error("Error: Alignment must be a power of two "
                           "(posix_memalign returned EINVAL)");
  else if (error != 0)
    throw std::bad_alloc();

  return mem;
}

/// Default alignment is set to 64 Byte, i.e., the most common cache-line size.
/// This alignment is sufficient at the least for AVX-512.
constexpr std::size_t default_alignment = 64;

} // namespace details

/// Typedef providing aligned::unique_ptr
template <class T> using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, details::Deleter<T>>;

/// For internal use only!
namespace details {

template <typename T> struct MakeUniq { typedef unique_ptr<T> single_object; };

template <typename T> struct MakeUniq<T[]> { typedef unique_ptr<T[]> array; };

template <typename T, std::size_t Bound> struct MakeUniq<T[Bound]> {
  struct invalid_type {};
};

} // namespace details

/// aligned::make_unique for single objects
template <typename T, std::size_t alignment = details::default_alignment,
          typename... Args>
inline typename details::MakeUniq<T>::single_object
make_unique(Args &&... args) {
  // Placement-new into aligned memory
  // We use constructor with "{}" to prevent narrowing
  return unique_ptr<T>(new (details::alloc<T, alignment>(1))
                           T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}

/// aligned::make_unique for arrays of unknown bound
template <typename T, std::size_t alignment = details::default_alignment>
inline typename details::MakeUniq<T>::array make_unique(std::size_t num) {
  // We are not using "new", which would prevent allocation of
  // non-default-constructible types, so we need to verify explicitly
  static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<
                    typename std::remove_extent<T>::type>::value,
                "Error: aligned::make_unique<T[]> supports only "
                "default-constructible types");
  static_assert(std::is_pod<
                    typename std::remove_extent<T>::type>::value,
                "Error: aligned::make_unique<T[]> supports only "
                "pod types");
  return unique_ptr<T>(details::alloc<T, alignment>(num));
}

/// Disable aligned::make_unique for arrays of known bound
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline typename details::MakeUniq<T>::invalid_type
make_unique(Args &&...) = delete;

} // namespace aligned

#endif // ALIGNED_H
```

Based on that we can allocate aligned memory (in this example I use the default alignment of 64 bytes instead of specifying it explicitly as a second template argument):

```
#include "aligned.h"

struct Foo {
  Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){};
  int x;
  int y;
};

int main() {

  // Single object

  auto x = aligned::make_unique<double>(16.0);

  // Forbidden thanks to "{}" --- did the user want to write
  // aligned::make_unique<double[]>(16)?
  // auto x = aligned::make_unique<double>(16);

  auto foo = aligned::make_unique<Foo>(3, 4);

  // Array

  auto y = aligned::make_unique<double[]>(16);

  // Disabled for arrays of known bounds:
  // auto y = aligned::make_unique<double[16]>(16);

  // Forbidden --- there is no default constructor:
  // auto foo = aligned::make_unique<Foo[]>(16);

  // Forbidden --- calling constructor & destructors on each array element is
  // not implemented:
  // auto s = aligned::make_unique<std::string[]>(16);
}
```

Is there any flaw or problem in my solution?

As @T.C. pointed out in a comment on Stack Overflow (where I had previously posted this question) there is a problem when allocating an array of, e.g., `std::string`, because constructors and destructors must be called in that case. Therefore I currently disabled `make_unique<T[]>` for non-POD types, but I would also appreciate a generic solution for that.

Comment: You still have to call the destructor for arrays.

Comment: @LokiAstari Could you please elaborate, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: `new` does not align memory to a sufficient extent when you want to use SSE, AVX, or other vector-instruction sets. For example, for SSE you need 16 byte alignment, for AVX 32 byte alignment. `new` would align a `float` to 4 byte or a `double` to 8 byte, but that is not enough. I will edit the question to mention this.

Comment: `posix_memalign` is not portable, `std::align` + `placement new` should be enough to make your code portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks reasonable to me. Good use of standard components to build the thing you want!

---

```
TYPE *mem = 0;
int error = posix_memalign((void **)&mem, align, sizeof(TYPE) * num);
```

I'd have written

```
void *mem = nullptr;
int error = posix_memalign(&mem, align, sizeof(TYPE) * num);
```

to get rid of the ugly casts and `0`-as-null. (Then return `static_cast<TYPE*>(mem)`.)

---

```
template <class T> using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, details::Deleter<T>>;
```

I have to keep in mind while reading your code that `unique_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>` are different types (despite being spelled the same). That's a good design choice for the *user* of your library, but it's a terrible design choice for the *reader* of your library. Therefore, IMO you should create a *new* name for your type in this file, e.g. `details::uniq_ptr`; and then at the very end of the file you should introduce `template<class T> using unique_ptr = details::uniq_ptr<T>;`. That way you get the best of both worlds: the *user* gets two things with the same name, and the *library reader* gets distinct names for distinct concepts.

---

For `make_unique<T[]>`, you'll have to return an `aligned::unique_ptr<T[]>`, which must remember the size of the array (or else retrieve it from something like `malloc_usable_size` or `_msize`, but those are problematic because they're analogous to `vector::capacity` instead of `vector::size`. You don't want to destroy more items than the user provided). Fortunately you can *partially specialize* your `unique_ptr` template so that `unique_ptr<T[]>` has that extra "size" member. (The STL's `unique_ptr` is also specialized for `T[]`, but doesn't keep that explicit "size" member because `operator delete[]` doesn't need it. Instead, it's specialized to provide a different set of accessor operators: `[]` instead of `*` and so on.)

---

```
// We use constructor with "{}" to prevent narrowing

// Forbidden thanks to "{}" --- did the user want to write
// aligned::make_unique<double[]>(16)?
// auto x = aligned::make_unique<double>(16);
```

This is a breaking change / deliberate asymmetry compared to `std::unique_ptr<T>`. What's wrong with narrowing? Your example implies that you're worried someone might accidentally leave the `[]` off an array type, but that's pretty far-fetched, isn't it?

Comment: I agree with your comments 1,2, and 4. I do not quite understand what you mean in your 3rd comment though. `posix_memalign` stores the size somehow, so `free` will do its job properly.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion in your 2nd comment: You give `details::uniq_ptr` as an example. Do you see any reason why I should not just spell out the type including the namespace name, i.e., write `aligned::unique_ptr` everywhere in the header?

Comment: @simon re 3rd comment: You asked how `unique_ptr<T[]>` for non-POD `T` should figure out how many objects to destroy. The answer is, you'll have to keep track of that in a member variable or else rely on `_msize` to guess how many you have. @simon re 2nd comment: Sure, I'd be reasonably happy with consistent use of `std::unique_ptr` and `aligned::unique_ptr` (and no use of unqualified `unique_ptr`... except that some uses (such as in constructor declarations) *have* to be unqualified; that might be a bit confusing. It's still strictly better than your original all-unqualified approach, though!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question on stackoverflow and it got me thinking there. I started to wonder if you could do what you wanted in a portable way using only the c++11 standard, while leveraging existing types to guarantee exception safety, RAII etc.

This is what I came up with:

```
template<class T, size_t Alignment = 64>
struct aligned_ptr {

    static constexpr size_t alignment = (Alignment < alignof(T)) ? alignof(T) : Alignment;
    static constexpr size_t buffer_size = alignment + sizeof(T) - 1;


    template<class...Args>
    aligned_ptr(Args&&...args)
    : _memory { new uint8_t[buffer_size] }
    , _object { make_object_pointer(_memory.get(), std::forward<Args>(args)...), &deleter }
    {
    }

    T* get() const noexcept {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(_object.get());
    }

private:
    static void deleter(T* p) noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<T>().~T()))
    {
        p->~T();
        // note: not freed
    }

    template<class...Args>
    T* make_object_pointer(uint8_t* buffer, Args&&...args)
    {
        auto addr_v = reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer);
        auto space = buffer_size;
        std::align(alignment, sizeof(T), addr_v, space);
        auto address = reinterpret_cast<T*>(addr_v);
        new (address) T (std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return address;
    }


private:
    // NOTE: order matters. memory before object
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> _memory;
    std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(T*)> _object;
};
```

Some work could be done on allocation to reduce waste (pre-caching etc) but I think it's a solid footing:

Comment: Can you explain your code at all, how it differs from the existing code? The purpose of Codereview.se is not to write new code; it's to critique the existing code and explain how it can be improved.

Comment: This code provides examples of how the author can remove all non-portable code, for example the posix_ calls.

Comment: I am not sure I get your intention. What part of my solution would you replace by your code? The intention of my code is to explicitly provide an interface as provided by `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`, so if a user needs aligned memory, he can simply use `aligned::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @Simon your code is not portable (`posix_memalign`). How would you write your `aligned_ptr` class if you couldn't use `posix_memalign`? The C++ standard provides `std::align` and `placement new`, so @Richard uses those to avoid using `posix_memalign`. As a consequence @Richard's suggestion works in non-POSIX environments.

Comment: @gnzlbg I used `posix_memalign` merely as an example. You can certainly replace it with something portable without impacting the rest of the design. @Richard's answer left things rather unclear (not providing functionality along the lines of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`, which was the original intention).

Comment: IIUC @RichardHodges only attempted to answer how one could replace `posix_memalign` with something portable, nothing more nothing less.